# Inter-process communication in Lua

Tags: lua, ipc

I have two applications (both pure Lua, on Windows) and they should be able to talk to each other. I used luasocket TCP/IP module with success; but I want to know what other methods can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Steve Donovan's [winapi](https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi) library supports IPC through named pipes, which are similar to Unix domain sockets.

Examples are available [here](http://stevedonovan.github.com/winapi/topics/readme.md.html#Pipe_Server) and [here](http://stevedonovan.github.com/winapi/examples/pipe-server.lua.html).

Comment: Thanks man. But i couldn't find any "winapi.lua" module to import into my apps (i.e. require"winapi.lua")???

Comment: winapi is a C module; you can download the DLL [here](https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi/downloads).  Put it somewhere in your package.cpath (`print(package.cpath)` shows which directories you can use) and load it with `require "winapi"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something multi-platform, consider 0MQ; Lua binding [here](https://github.com/Neopallium/lua-zmq)

Answer (score 2):

I like to use [OiL](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~maia/oil/) to communicate between application. It's very easy to use and can be used multi-platform (via CORBA).

You can create a simple interface and create structured data, much more easy to understand than parsing a message by yourself.